# Can't select all / deselect all in Object mode

Tags: modeling, objects, 3d-view, transforms

I have a problem only in a certain project in blender, one that is very important to me so if anyone could help I would appreciate it a lot!

So here's the problem:

Basically, I can't select all / deselect all objects in object mode. (Shortcut A but even with the select menu > deselect all / select all nothing works).

The objects ARE selectable in the object layer (Viewport selection disable thing).

I am in object mode so it's not that.

Manipulate Center points is unchecked.

As I said earlier, this is only an issue with a certain Blender Project and it works fine on the rest so maybe I missed something?
There wasn't an issue when I closed my project but a day later this issue suddenly out of nowhere happened.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Those couuld be corrupted somehow, if nothing works, try a new fresh file and append the whole scene from the strange file, or single objects, etc.

Comment: Hard to tell from description alone. Could you post a **simplified** file demonstrating the problem?

Comment: It is corrupted pretty sure. If I put a new object I can suddenly select everything but only for like 1 minute before it messes up again